# How can I check whether a recipient already received a DocuSign envelope of same template or not?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a recipient's email address and a template id of my DocuSign. Is there any way to check whether there is already an envelope of my checking template id which is sent to my checking recipient's email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the DocuSign platform has a way of checking if a given user has been sent an envelope that used a specific template from your account.  If you have a need to remember this info then your integration code/logic would need to remember that outside of the DocuSign platform.